# Database add connection screen

Tags: c#, .net, database

A while ago a created an application that would prompt the user for the database connection details. I found that Microsoft had created a control specifically for this purpose and they had released the whole thing (source code included).

It produced a display similar to the following:

[image: Add Connection Screenshot]

I'm trying to find this control again and I can't remember where I found it or what the name was.

Anyone any ideas where I would find this (I'm sure it was on codeplex or something like that)?

Answer (score 1):

I just found it lol, here is the link:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection

Comment: you need the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.dll, it should be installed with visual studio, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.data.dataconnectiondialog%28v=vs.90%29.aspx